# How does "pid = fork();" assigns "pid = 0" in child process?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork, pid

I read in [Beej's `fork()` primer](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/fork.html) that when I call `pid = fork();`, the parent process gets pid of child process, while inside the child process `pid = 0`.

Now, since child process starts executing part of code **after** the `fork()` statement, how does `pid` gets value`0`?

Comment: [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) has a nice chapter explaining that. But understanding `fork` is difficult...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whoever told you "the child process starts executing after the fork statement" was poorly expressing the intended meaning. The point at which two processes come to exist is, conceptually, "inside" the fork call; it returns once in the parent and once in the child, with different return values in each.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I didn't know `fork()` returns twice.